# How to include a latent factor residual / disturbance term in lavaan?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

Sample code:

```
library(lavaan)
model <- '
#latent variable definition
visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3

#regressions
visual ~ x4
visual ~ x5
visual ~ x6

#(co)variances
visual ~~ visual
'

fit <- sem(model, data = HolzingerSwineford1939)
summary(fit)
inspect(fit,"estimates")
```

Because I believe that not all variance of `visual` is explained by `x4`, `x5`, and `x6`, I want to make sure a latent factor residual (disturbance term) is included to represent the remainder of the variance found in `visual`.

I've included the following code in an attempt to include residual variance of the latent variable: `visual ~~ visual`, but I'm pretty sure this simply represents the variance, not the residual variance, and is therefore redundant.

Under the "variances:" heading in the output from `summary(fit)` the estimate obtained for `visual` is 0.608. When `visual ~~ visual` is removed from the code, I get the exact same value.

Under the "$psi" heading in the output from the function `inspect(fit,"estimates")` the intersection of `visual` with itself yields an identical value: 0.608. When `visual ~~ visual` is removed, again I get the same result.

I believe both of these values are estimates of the total variance of `visual`, not the residual variance. So how is the estimate of residual variance of `visual` obtained?

In the lavaan tutorial, it says "residual variances are added automatically", but I believe this may be referring only to residual variances of observed variables, not to the residual variances of latent variables.

Comment: The line `visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3` means that x1, x2, and x3 are indicators of the latent factor. Graphically, the arrows go from visual to x1, x2, and x3. In this model, x1, x2, and x3 are explained (partly) by visual, not the other way round. This is a CFA model and so visual is an exogenous variable. You can verify this by `lavNames(fit, "lv.x")`. Therefore, it does not have a residual term.
Perhaps what you are thinking about is a model with formative indicators?

Comment: @sfcheung you're right, that's an error on my part. I'll edit the sample code to reflect my actual model. In my actual model I have both indicators of the latent factor (arrows from observed variables to the latent variable) as well as pathways from the latent variable pointing to observed variables.

Comment: `visual ~~ visual` can have one of two different meanings. If `visual` is an exogenous variable, then `visual ~~ visual` the variance of `visual`. However, if `visual` is an endogenous variable, then `visual ~~ visual` is the residual variance of `visual`. If `visual` is an endogenous variable with a disturbance (error term), then only its residual variance is a model parameter. Its variance is not a parameter and so you would not see this value in the output.  In the output of `summary()`, you can see the row of the "variance" of `visual` is `.visual`, with a dot. It is the residual variance.

Comment: The same holds true for the `psi` matrix. It contains the variances and covariances of exogenous variables and error terms/disturbance term, if any. Therefore, `visual` in the `psi` matrix refers to the variances and covariances of the disturbance of `visual`, not the variance of `visual`. If you type `lavInspect(fit, "cov.lv")`, which returns the implied variances and covariances of the latent variables, you can see that the implied variance of `visual` is 0.78, not 0.608.

Comment: @sfcheung thank you for your comments, they are very helpful! It appears that error terms are, then, automatically added for all endogenous variables, including endogenous latent variables. I say this because when 'visual ~~ visual' is removed from the code, the "variance" row of the output of 'summary()' still returns '.visual', a residual variance.

Comment: That is because you use the `sem()` function, which is a wrapper around the bare-bones `lavaan()` function that does not "turn on" any useful `?lavOptions` like automatically estimating variances (as almost any model would).  This option is "turned on" by the `sem()` or `cfa()` function, which internally sets `auto.var=TRUE`.